# Python Function monthrange

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following:
I imported an excel list called example with the date in the form day-month-year, which is the index, and then I have in a second column the corresponding volumes.

With python I extracted the month and the year.

```
example['Year']= example.index.year
example['month']= example.index.month
```

Now I want to get the days per month

I tried:

```
x=monthrange(example['Year'], example'[month'])
```

Does not work, the result is ambiguous.

```
for i in example['year']:
   for j in eaxmaple['month']:
       x=monthrange(i,j)
```

does not work either, since it does not combine the year and month, it just loops through all year, and then trhough all months.

How do I solve this?
I would like to add a colum with the days per month, so I have one colum with the date, one column with the year, one column with the month and one with the days per month

Comment: What is the definition of `monthrange`?  What is in `example['year']` and `example['month']`?  What *should* your results be?

Comment: Provide all the necessary code so that we can help you

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Does this work? :

```
x=[monthrange(i, j) for (i, j) in zip(example['Year'], example['month'])]
```

Or if you want only the days in month:

```
x=[monthrange(i, j)[1] for (i, j) in zip(example['Year'], example['month'])]
```

Or with pandas:

```
example['days_in_month'] = example.apply(lambda df: monthrange(df['Year'], df['month']))
```